# jquery dependend form elements validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validate

I am using a very long expandable form. For example if `question 1` is answered with "Yes", `question 1.1` will show and so on.

This works well with the following (simple) jquery script:

**Selectmenu**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".question").change(function() {
            var itemValue = $(this).children(':selected').val();

            if(itemValue != "" &&  itemValue != "N")
            {
                $(".questiont").show();
            }
            else
            {
                $(".questiont").hide();
            }
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="question1[]" class='required txtBox'>
              <option selected="selected"></option>
              <option value="J">Yes</option>
              <option value="N">No</option>
            </select>
<table>
    <tr class="questiont" style="display:none; border-collapse:collapse;">
              <td>4.2</td>
              <td>Textarea</td>
              <td><textarea name="questiont[]" class="txtBox"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is, that if 1 is "Yes" and thus 1.1 is shown, 1.1 should be filled. I am using jQuery validate for that.

The problem is that i don't know how to combine the validation with a hidden or shown status.

Comment: Can you share the generated HTML?

Comment: Done! And i removed the PHP as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
if(itemValue != "" &&  itemValue != "N")
            {
                $(".questiont").show();
                $('.questiont').toggleClass('required');
            }
            else
            {
                $(".questiont").hide();
                $('.questiont').toggleClass('required');
            }
```

Comment: This I am trying, but i used addclass('required'), it doesn't validate though. I'll try toggleClass

Comment: I think this one did it! I am still playing with it, but it looks fine!

Comment: Mmhh it behaved weird, for example when i load the form, select no and submit, the extra field was still required (while it shouldn't be). If i played with it, it didn't became required anymore (while it should). I now tried removeClass and addClass. Testing that now.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to select and validate when the two related elements are nested in a separate container element. You can then select the parent container with the `closest()` method and validate according to your logic.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="question_container">    
    <select name="question1[]" class='required txtBox'>
        <option selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="J">Yes</option>
        <option value="N">No</option>
    </select>
    <table>
        <tr class="questiont" style="display:none; border-collapse:collapse;">
            <td>4.2</td>
            <td>Textarea</td>
            <td><textarea name="questiont[]" class="txtBox"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.question_container select.required').change(
    function() {
        var question_container = $(this).closest('.question_container');
        var questiont          = question_container.find('.questiont textarea');

        if ($(this).val() == 'yes' && !$.trim(questiont.val())) {
            // ... error logic goes here
            // For example:
            question_container.addClass('with_error');
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your work. I agree with you that this would be the best solution in this example, but the form contains several "Yes" options where the extra field doesn't need to be validated. Other than that, it sometimes needs validation on "No" or when a checkbox is selected etc. Is it possible to check the questions one by one and add a class "required" to the textarea (in this example)?

Comment: Edited my example after rereading the question. Note that errors are now triggered upon `change()`, as in your example. The event is now also bound to `select` elements of `required` class only. Using class selectors, you can mark each field or set of fields to use (or not use) any validation logic.

Comment: Thanks for all your work, i just accepted an other answer but upvoted your comment and answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the [jQuery validate plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) which will ignore hidden fields by default.

Any input element that satisfies jQuery selector ":hidden" will be ignored, once the element is shown then it will be validated according to the rules you have specified for it.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't toggle the validation.. This would be ideal.

Comment: maybe you are using an older version of the validate plugin, you need >= 1.9.0

Comment: I would try it, it will save you a lot of toggling classes